# Read local XML file with Qt Quick XmlListModel

Tags: xml, qt, qtquick2

I have XML file (data.xml) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table name="atome">
    <column name="id">1</column>
    <column name="nom">Hydrogène</column>
    <column name="slug">hydrogene</column>
    <column name="electron">1</column>
    <column name="numero">1</column>
    <column name="symbole">H</column>
    <column name="info_groupe">1</column>
    <column name="info_periode">1</column>
    <column name="info_bloc">s</column>
</table>
```

I can view content of this XML file with QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    XmlListModel {
        id: model
        source: "qrc:/data.xml"
        query: "/table/column"
        XmlRole { name: "columnName"; query: "string(@name)" }
        XmlRole { name: "columnValue"; query: "string()" }
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: model
        delegate:  Text { text: columnName + " = " + columnValue }
    }

}
```

But if I put file to /var/tmp/data.xml and change source to source: "/var/tmp/data.xml", I cannot show any thing.

source: "/var/tmp/data.xml"

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

OK, it should be "source: "file:///var/tmp/data.xml""